# after form onSubmit , setstate is not working

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

Im very new at coding, and have a question on below issues..
I made a form with buttons inside,
and tried to put setStatus in the onSubmit function
in order to change the status as the form submitted.

it seems like axios.post part is working, but
setStatus isn't..
could anyone kindly advise how to fix it..? would be highly appreciated!

```js
const handleSubmit=async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
       const reponse = await axios.post(`http:///`,
            {...info})
            setScore("") 
            setStatus(2)
    }

const ChangeHandler=(e)=>{
        const selected = e.target.value
        const btnSection = document.querySelector(".btn_section")

        if(selectedoption !=="......."){   
            btnSection.innerHTML =`<button type="submit">Submit </button>`
            setReason(selected)
            setScore(score)  
        }else if(selectedoption ==="Select the Reason"){
            alert("Please select the Reason")
        }
    }
```

```js
<div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <button type="submit" 
                onClick={()=> {
                setScore(1)
                setReason("!")
            }}>Yes</button>
   
           {btnPressed? (
            <>
                    <p>...</p>   
                    <select onChange={ChangeHandler}>
                    <option>Select</option>
                    {Lists.map((list, index)=>{
                        return(
                        <option
                        key={index} value={name}>{name}</option>
                        )
                        })}
                        </select>
                        <div className="btn_section" ></div>
                    </>
           ):(
            <button onClick={BtnHandler}>No</button>
           )}
             </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: when do you want to call this -  `onClick={()=> { setScore(1); setReason("!") }}`

Comment: I suggest that you should call handleSubmit on button click event. Also, don't manipulate DOM as react offers a virtual DOM for you.

Comment: What makes you think `setStatus` or any other state updaters aren't working? Why are you trying to inset a button into the DOM via the change handler?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` of button is not getting called because your button `type` is `submit` . When your button type is `submit` and if you click the button the forms `handleSubmit` function will get called .

If you want to do update the state . Then you should consider moving the setState call inside the `handleSubmit` function .